# Xlib: simple program consumes 90% CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, xlib, xorg

A very simple screensaver works great for several hours, then suddenly the screen turns black, and CPU jumps to 90%. The memory consumption jumps just by 4kB and stays unchanged.

```
while (1)
{   
    XClearWindow(dpy, win);
    // draw a logo 259x64 pixels
    XPutImage(dpy, win, gc, img, 0, 0, random()%(WIDTH-LOGO_WIDTH), random()%(HEIGHT-LOGO_HEIGHT), LOGO_WIDTH, LOGO_HEIGHT);
    XFlush(dpy);
    usleep (DELAY_US);    // 1 sec delay
}
```

top's output:

```
   PID USER     PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                 
  2717 aspen    20   0   12580   1868   1504 R 91.5  0.4 838:05.68 screensaver
```

EDIT:
Another thread processes events. When the program starts consuming much CPU nothing is printed out, i.e. there are no events.

```
static events()
{
    XNextEvent (dpy, &event);
    switch (event.type)
    {   
        case ButtonPress:
            XCloseDisplay (dpy);
            printf ("Let's go work!\n");
            exit (1);
        default:
            printf ("Event: %d\n", event.type);
    }
}
```

gdb output (using core dumped by gcore):

```
(gdb) thread 1
[Switching to thread 1 (Thread 0xb6f21000 (LWP 2654))]
#0  0xb6e22ffa in _XReply () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6e22ffa in _XReply () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so.6
#1  0xb6e24b2c in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0xb6c54470 (LWP 2655))]
#0  0xb6d60580 in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84      in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6d60580 in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0xb6cb3ec4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb.so.1
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Thanks for advises/directions to troubleshoot.

xorg-server 1.19.2 (Debian 9.1)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Did you try gcore? Try to get an image dump at the top Cpu usage moment and debug. Please make sure that you are running a -g compiled version :) There's no way that the stackoverflow public knows that answer, unless someone already has a fix...

Comment: You should use `XNextEvent` or something similar. The X11 server *is sending* events (even to simple applications). You need to process them (following  ICCCM & EWMH)

Comment: I can provide an example of a program that does 90 percent cpu load. Two nested loops. The outside loop just resets the counter of the inside loop and within the inside you just increase the counter by one until less than some max int. It's an infinite nested loop and still pretty simple :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch , thanks, that makes sense. So what if I don't process events at all? Is it bad? (please excuse my ignorance, I don't have any Xlib programming experience).
In this particular program I care of ButtonPress events only:
        `XNextEvent (dpy, &event);
         switch (event.type)
         {   
            case ButtonPress:
            XCloseDisplay (dpy);
            exit (1);
        }`
I would guess that the CPU jumps to 90% when X11 server starts sending numerous events for some reason.

Comment: `XNextEvent` would call [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or some *blocking* [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), which don't eat CPU time and wait for input. BTW, X11 tends to become obsolete, replaced by [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)). You could use `strace` also

Comment: @KrassiEm , I tried **gdb** with core dumped by **gcore**, thanks for advice.
I've updated my post with that info. Not sure whether that can shed more light.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find the root cause, but the problem is solved by removing the second thread which was processing events.
Instead I added a non-blocking function `XCheckTypedEvent()` in the main loop.
So the original problem was somehow related to multi-threading per se: even though the second thread was idle waiting for events (and there were no events!) with blocking `XNextEvent()`, the main loop failed after several hours.